# Input error icon and clear icon at the same time

Tags: input-fields, validation

In Material design documentation we see optional icons inside an input. What if I want to have a clear icon (3) and display an error icon (2) at the same time? Side by side?
[image: Material design input icons]

Comment: https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/components/dropdown/usage : Scrolldown to invalid section ~ They place it side by side

Answer (score 1):

Ah that’s going to be tricky – is moving away from Material Design’s form fields out of the question?

I say this because on top of the problem you raise, [float labels have a load of usability issues](https://adamsilver.io/articles/float-labels-are-problematic/).

If you’re particularly interested in designing forms that are easy to use, check out [Form Design Patterns](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/10/form-design-patterns-excerpt-a-registration-form/) published by Smashing Magazine.

I cover all these things and more in lots of detail. Sorry to plug my own thing, but poured months into it and it genuinely might help you.